# Тип человека (название)

Tags: названия

Как назвать человека, который свои капризы (нежелание что-либо делать) выдает за убеждение? Например человек, который не хочет заниматься обучением 10 минут и желает ему больше посвящать, говорит, что 10 минут якобы "сосут энергию", "дразнят" и являются вредоносными.

Comment: Назовите его Манипулятор..........

Answer (score 1):

Приведённый пример говорит о том, что это нормальный человек. Он прав. Чему можно научить за 10 минут? Если только каким-то физическим нетрудным движениям. Если уж заниматься, то хотя бы 45 минут, лучше час.

А вообще, есть такие термины:

Фразер — человек, который любит фразу, напыщенную речь. За красивыми словами может скрываться простая лень.

Резонер — Человек, который любит рассуждать длинно и нравоучительно, но ничего не делает.